# How to avoid HSTS error by hosts redirect with self-signed certificate?

Tags: ssl, hosts, self-signed-certificate, hsts

I created this records in windows hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 a.domain.name
127.0.0.1 b.domain.name
127.0.0.1 c.domain.name
```

where
 
**127.0.0.1** - ip of my server
**[a,b,c].domain.name** - domains wich from i need to get redirect to my server


So, how i need to create self-signed certificate to get trusted from browsers and avoid HSTS error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify: A self-signed certificate will only be trusted by browsers that manually have trusted this certificate. Everybody else will get warnings.

In Windows you would run the powershell command `New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\my -DnsName *.test.com -FriendlyName "star_test_com-2020" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(2)` to create a self-signed wildcard certificate for test.com with a two year lifetime.

Then you can search your start menu for `manage computer certificates` to export the certificate for use on other computers. If you just want to trust the certificate on a client, you'll want a copy that is exported *without* the private key. If you want to present the certificate from a server, you need a copy that is exported *with* the private key.

For your own computer to trust the certificate, it needs to exist in the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` in the certificate manager. You can copy it there from the `Personal` store by right-dragging it there with your mouse.

For (Windows/Microsoft) services to be able to present the certificate, it usually needs to exist in the LocalMachine\Personal store.

---

However: If you want to present services publicly, you will want to use a CA-signed certificate. It's definitely cheapest and probably easiest to go via [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org), but I have no experience using them for Windows servers. The alternative is to pay for certificates from a commercial CA.